# Browse url at point when clicking and pressing super

Tags: key-bindings, minibuffer, url

I am trying to make emacs open the url displayed under the current point when I left click and press the super key at the same time.

I am trying with this code but it does not work

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<s-mouse-1>") #'(lambda ()
                                   (interactive)
                                   (browse-url)
                                   (kbd "<return>")))
```

The `(kbd "<return>")` part would be used to invoke to invoke a return in the mini-buffer: when `browse-url` is called the user must confirm to open the url by pressing return in the mini-buffer.

Comment: Have you tried `(browse-url (thing-at-point 'url t))`?

Comment: Have you unbound the `mouse down` binding? multiple-cursors.el has a explanation here: https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el#binding-mouse-events

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 I get `wrong type argument: stringp, nil` when clicking

Comment: @YuanFu I can bind the event, the problem is the code within the lambda which does not work

Comment: Try `(browse-url (browse-url-url-at-point))`, that's what `browse-url` uses in its source. @DoMiNeLa10♦ 's snippet should work tho. You probably get that error because `(thing-at-point 'url t)` didn't find the url and returned `nil`.

Comment: Don't bother to use `#'` with lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the *mouse* to invoke your command, so you *need the command to accept a mouse event* as argument.  This does what you want:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<s-mouse-1>")
                (lambda (event)
                  (interactive (list last-command-event))
                  (posn-set-point (event-end event))
                  (browse-url (thing-at-point 'url t))))
```

(You might also need to set `<s-down-mouse-1>` to `nil`.  Or you might need to change the code above to use `<s-down-mouse-1>`.  It depends on what you're starting with.)

---

`(kbd "<return>")` does nothing in your code, BTW. It just returns the vector `[return]`, which is a more internal way of writing the key sequence of hitting the Return key.  Return such a vector from a function does not invoke a command.